# Multiple Like SQL Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
 select * from m3fdbprd.cmnusr
 where juultp = 1
 and jutx40 <> LIKE 'M3%' OR jutx40 <> LIKE 'MeC%'
 order by jutx40
```

I am getting an error:

> SQL0104 - Token 'M3%' was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT
>   WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET.

where I am trying to do a multiple like, I am running this query to display all values in m3fdbprd.cmnusr where in the column jutx40 the value does not start with M3 or Mec.

Can you please advise?

I am running against an MS sql server database.

Comment: `SQL0104`  does not looks like a `SQL Server` error message. Googling shows that is is more likely `DB2`

Answer (score 5):

Use `NOT LIKE`.  I'm also pretty sure you want `AND` and not `OR`:

```
select *
from m3fdbprd.cmnusr
where juultp = 1 and
      jutx40 not like 'M3%' and jutx40 not LIKE 'MeC%'
order by jutx40
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NOT` instead of `<>`

```
 select * from m3fdbprd.cmnusr
 where juultp = 1
 and jutx40 NOT LIKE 'M3%' OR jutx40 NOT LIKE 'MeC%'
 order by jutx40
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `NOT` with parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM m3fdbprd.cmnusr
WHERE juultp = 1
AND NOT (jutx40 LIKE 'M3%' OR jutx40 LIKE 'MeC%')
ORDER BY jutx40
```